# How to clear values that are stored in service in angular 6 application?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angular7

Thanks in advance.
I am beginner to angular 6.I need help regarding angular 6 services. 
With in my application, we are using angular 6 services for storing and fetching data. At some instance, I need to clear the service. Is there any angular inbuilt method to clear the service or I need to do it manually y assigning it to default values.

Comment: It would be handy if you could show some code/the services.  But if you want to clear the service, you can set the properties back to undefined.

Comment: there is no inbuilt method for the clearing values from service. but you can try re-instantiate the service to set it default values

Comment: Thank you, It could be helpful to me @hypenate

Comment: Yes, I'll try to re-instantiate the service. Thank you!!!@changulpaye

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. If you logout a user, how do you clean all singleton service data from that user? You will have to instantiate every service of the app to clear it?

Answer (score 1):

We don't have any specific methods to clear angular service variables, but we can do this just with assigning empty objects to them.

1. it's an object then -- `this.service.objectProperty = undefined;`
2. Array --  `this.service.arrayProperty = [];`
3. if it's Map -- `this.service.mapProperty.clear();`

for more info about this, [*refer here*](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4)

Comment: This is kind of obvious and do not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

On component A I use Angulars DI system to automatically inject the same `ApiService` on all the components.

On component B however I set my own version of the `ApiService`.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'; 
import { ApiService } from './api.service'; 

// ./a.component.ts
@Component({ 
  selector: 'app-root', 
  templateUrl: './app.component.html', 
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'] 
}) 
export class AComponent {     
  public constructor(api:ApiService){ 
  } 
} 

 // ./b.component.ts
 @Component({ 
  selector: 'app-root', 
  templateUrl: './app.component.html', 
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'] 
  providers: [APIService], <------ use a "new" APIService
 })

 export class BComponent { 

  public constructor(api:ApiService){        
  }  
}
```

But if you would just want to clear a value, you could use this in your component:
`this.api.someProperty = undefined`.
Note that this will clear the property for all components using `ApiService` that use the Angular DI system.